# Is there a way for std::setprecision to control significant figures (not decimal places) when combined with std::fixed?

Tags: c++

`std::setprecision` normally controls the number of significant figures (not decimal places). However, when combined with `std::fixed`, it controls the number of decimal places (not significant figures)! Is there a way to both suppress scientific notation (like `std::fixed` does) and specify the number of significant figures (not decimal places)?

Comment: Lets say you have the value `100,000` and you want 4 significant figures.  How would you do that without resorting to `1.000e5`?

Comment: `100,000` is already <=4 SF, so no change is required. Another example: a representation of `123,456` as 4 SF is `123,500`.

Comment: I'd just write a function that converts it to a string in whatever format you want.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but one challenge is that it's awkward to calculate the number of DP (to give to `std::setprecision`) given a desired number of SF: for example, it requires taking the log base 10 to see how many digits are used on the left of the decimal point. It works, but I'd rather use something built in if possible.